# PostgreSQL command history on Windows

Tags: postgresql, windows, psql

I am trying to use `psql` from a Windows command prompt (`cmd.exe`), but can't access any of the previous commands with the up/down cursors. I could also really do with finding out where the PostgreSQL equivalent to `.bash_history` is (if there is one), as I could read the command history from there.

`\s` produces the following error:

> history is not supported by this installation

Is there a way to get the `psql` command history on Windows?

Comment: What platform are you on? And how did you install PostgreSQL exactly?

Comment: @ypercube Does he mean "command prompt windows" or "Windows" the OS? His reference to .bash_history is confusing, whereas he talks about "command prompt" and not "shell".

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the bash, too (and removed the comment.)

Comment: Have you tried PowerShell?

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, there isn't an exact equivalent to a `.bash_history` because `cmd.exe` is an intrinsically different type of shell. I think you're referring more to the `.psql_history` (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17924906/2074605)).

There is a "[SQL Shell](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4e9dda52-e8d2-158a-0a59-248a37fe0e09%40orange.fr)" available in the SQL Command Line Terminal of the EnterpriseDB Windows distribution of PostgreSQL that supports a command history. However, I prefer to use the Windows command prompt instead of the GUI.

The error message you are getting indicates that `psql.exe` was built without `readline` support ([reference](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/c5155d25-0e23-dadd-72d3-05a538d90a80%40orange.fr)).

The best way I have found to run `psql` via the normal Windows command prompt is to create a shortcut:

Target: `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /U /c "chcp 1252 & C:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\psql.exe -U database_username -d database_name"`

[image: psql shortcut]

The command history can be controlled via `Command history Buffer size` in the Options pane:

[image: psql shortcut options]

And you can adjust the scrollable output via `Screen Buffer Height` in the Layout pane:

[image: psql shortcut layout]

This will get you a history via the up and down arrows, but only within your current session. It will not be preserved across sessions.